# Retrieving a URL via a Wufoo Form

Tags: wordpress, forms, integration, wufoo

I'm pretty new to using wufoo forms and have been searching for a few days and can't quite find what I'm looking for.

I did find a number of articles about 'URL Modification' but not sure how to implement this for what I need.

We have a simple single wufoo form which is being used across 6 iterations of a client's domains (they are sector specific).

We want (in the email notification and response entry on wufoo) to record which site was used to complete the form (for analytical purposes).

In other words the email to the client should list:

```
Name: John Smith
Email: Johnsmith@mail.com
Phone: 555-123-1234
From: www.websiteversion1.com
```

The form is being integrated on Wordpress sites.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the form HTML to your site's templates and modify the form, using PHP to fill in the value of the site url. I don't think WuFoo will automatically fill that field in for you.

1. First of all, in your WuFoo account forms manager, add a website (url) field and make it visible for admins only (this is a Wufoo option).
2. Then copy the generated form into your own template.
3. Now modify your form template so that it grabs the site URL and fills it in for the `value` of the website field where you want it.

Your form template might look something like this:

```
<form class="wufoo-form" id="form3" name="form3" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Field1">Name</label>
        <input id="Field1" name="Field1" type="text" placeholder="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Field2">Email</label>
        <input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="email" placeholder="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Field3">Phone</label>
        <input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="tel" placeholder="" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group hidden">
        <label for="Field4">From</label>
        <input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Let's talk!</button>
        <input type="hidden" id="idstamp" name="idstamp" value="***the_id_for_your_form_wufoo***" />
    </div>
</form>
```